# asp.net mvc a grid of results with close buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms

Currently converting an old asp.net web forms page into a asp.net mvc version, and a little stuck on something that isn't a major deal, but would be a nice to have.

When the user logs in, they are taken to a messages page at /Alerts.  They can close individual messages by clicking the x's, and then if they close all the message they are moved onto another page automatically.

The original site did postbacks, so the URL stayed the same.  In my new version, I planned to make the x button a link, that went to /Alerts/Confirm/xx where xx is the id.  The problem is, after processing, the address bar stays on that url, whereas I'd like to leave it on /Alerts

The four solutions appear to be either:

1) using AJAX to do the processing;

2) a redirect back to /Alerts after processing;

3) replacing all the X links with a submit button, and using javascript to pass a different ID depending on which message is being acknowledged, so that I can change the Confirm method to an HttpPost-accepting Index method?

4) URL Rewrites? (not sure about this, just thought of as I wrote this)

Or am I missing something obvious that would do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with #1 and use Jquery to do it.

Or you could show/hide those messages using Jquery .show() .hide().  So, they would always be there, just hidden.  When they hit refresh they would show again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some sort of notification plugin for jquery, there are many available just google for it, [this page](http://webtoolkit4.me/2009/08/13/jquery-growl-likenotification-systems/) has about 6 examples, it is a bit old but you can get an idea.